# How to change GridView in MVC View Layout pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, listview, razor

I have customer table that has 20 columns. And using EntityFramework I created a controller than a View. Everything works well. Only Index.cshtml page it is larger than I expected. From left to right I have to bottom scroll.

My layout uses standard MVC GridView. Is it possible to change the grid view to something different like a ListView?

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you looked at your Site.css under the Content folder?

Comment: Thank you but I guess I need to view my data (20 columns) in Quick View mode...